# trying to understand how x86 addressing works

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to understand what happens in this 2 lines:

```
mov %esp,%edi
lea 0x10(%edi),%esi
```

First I save the current stack-pointer to the %edi-register. this is clear. But now... I jump 16 Byte back to the stack-area from the procedure before and save the address in the %esi-register? why should I do that? At this time, I don't know what this address contains. Can someone help me to explain the sense of this line?

Comment: If you don't know why you're doing it, why did you write it?

Comment: I don't wrote it. I'm just trying to understand the code.

Comment: okay, I was confused because you keep saying "I do this" and "I do that", implying that you wrote it. So I guess the other question is, "Why isn't the code commented, so it explains what they are looking for on the stack?" We don't know what's on the stack. Hopefully the original author does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the mov %esp,%edi, you can get the same result with:

```
 lea  0x10(%esp),%esi
```

The stack in the x86 grows "down", as you push things into the stack, %esp
gets smaller values (decremented by multiples of 4, matching the size of
"double-words" [32 bits] on the x86).

So what the lea is doing, is computing a location in the stack that was pushed
by some earlier computation.  Because 0x10 == 4* 0x4, it is finding the location of the
4th double-word up in the stack.

Usually following an lea, there are  operations that use the resulting address
to read or write a value at or near the lea-generated address.  What these operations
are doing depends on the rest of the program, which you didn't show us so there's
no way to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where in the function these instructions are, it is probably either a) loading the value of a parameter that was passed to the function on the stack, or b) loading the value of a local variable defined in the function, or c) something completely different that can't be guessed without more context.

Google the x86 and/or x86_64 ABI standards to find more information on what parameters are allowed to be passed on the stack vs in registers, how the stack frame is laid out, where local variables live, and many other things that will help understand compiler-generated assembly code.